# Simple zeroes of complex polynomial $f(\cdot,a)$: condition on $P(a)=\operatorname{Res}_z(f,f')$

Tags: polynomials, resultants

A polynomial in the complex variable $z$, whose coefficients are themselves complex polynomials in another complex variable $a$, looks like
$$
f\in\Bbb C[A][Z],\;\;f(z,a)=c_0(a)+c_1(a)z+\cdots+c_n(a)z^n
$$
with $c_j\in\Bbb C[A]$ of degree less or equal than $1$. Assume not all $c_j$ are constant and the leading coefficient $c_n\equiv1$.

I need to prove that the roots of $z\mapsto f(z,a)$ are simple for all $a\in\Bbb C$ except for a finite number of $a$.

A root of $f(\cdot,a)$ is simple if and only if it is not a root of $f'(\cdot,a)$ and this happens if and only if the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) $P(a)$ of $f(\cdot,a),f'(\cdot,a)$ doesn't vanish.

Now $P\in\Bbb C[A]$, hence if it is not constantly $0$, then the claim is true (if $P$ is non constant then it vanishes for a finite number of values of $a$, while if it is constant and non zero, $f(\cdot,a)$ and $f'(\cdot,a)$ don't share a zero for any $a$).

Is it always possible to exclude the case $P\equiv0$?

Comment: What about $f(z,a):=(z-a)^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the assumption that $c_j$ have degree less or equal than $1$. I am going to edit

Comment: $P=0$ if and only if $f$ has a multiple factor (a factor which is a power of some polynomial).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: sure, I wrote when I talked about the resultant. I was wondering how to prove that $P\equiv0$ is never the case in the setting above described

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true, as is shown by the polynomial $f(z,a):=(z-a)(z-1)^2$.